# Convert HEX with alpha into non Alpha assuming the background is white

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, transparency

I basically want to write the scss mix function in js

```js
const base = '#86bc25'
const fade = 13 // => 13% =>ff to dd in Hex so it would be #86bc25dd
const newColor = someFunction(base,fade) // should turn out to be #216076
```

Why I know the expected result? Used a colorpicker on the transparent color xD

Answer (score 1):

found the solution:

```js
const oldColor = '#004862' // to 216076
const fade = 0.13
function fadeColor(oldColor,fade){
let r = parseInt(oldColor.substring(1,3),16)
let g = parseInt(oldColor.substring(3,5),16)
let b = parseInt(oldColor.substring(5,7),16)

r = (Math.round((fade*255 + (1-fade)*r)).toString(16)).split('.')[0]
g = (Math.round((fade*255 + (1-fade)*g)).toString(16)).split('.')[0] 
b = (Math.round((fade*255 + (1-fade)*b)).toString(16)).split('.')[0]
return (r.length===1?'0'+r:r)+(g.length===1?'0'+g:g)+(b.length===1?'0'+b:b)
}

console.log(fadeColor(oldColor,fade))
```